# boost build b2/bjam build configuration

Tags: boost, build, config, bjam

I'm currently working on a c++ project that uses bjam (boost build) as a builder. For now I was quite happy with this build system and everything works nicely, however with one exception which I could not find an easy solution for:

I would like to have a build configuration of this project, in which the user is able to switch on or off certain modules and its dependencies (also automatic checks if software is not found -> disable module..). With dependencies I mean for example applications that require this module to work. So these applications should also not be built when the module is disabled.

Since I found nothing out there that could do this job for me, I created some variables in the jamroot (top level jamfile) that resemble the module structure of the project, and I use these variables in if statements within the appropriate jamfiles to switch on and off things. See below for an example:

Jamroot excerpt:

```
constant build_DataReader : 1 ;
constant build_RootReader : 1 ;
constant build_AsciiReader : 1 ;

if $(build_DataReader) {
  build-project DataReader ;
}
```

Jamfile for DataReader Module:

```
sources = [ glob *.cpp ] ;
if $(build_RootReader)
{
    build-project RootReader ;
    sources = $(sources) $(DATAREADER)/RootReader//RootReader ;
}
if $(build_AsciiReader)
{
    build-project AsciiReader ;
    sources = $(sources) $(DATAREADER)/AsciiReader//AsciiReader ;
}

# Build libDataReader.so
lib DataReader : 
        $(sources)
        ;

install dist : DataReader : <location>$(TOP)/lib ;
```

However this is not a very elegant solution, as I would constantly have to update these hardcoded if statements when dependencies change etc.. In addition it is annoying to have to construct this tree structure of the modules in the project myself, as boost build is constructing the same thing internally by itself. Is there some kind of option in boost build to make the building of applications optional in case some requirements are not built in the current build process?

The only solution I see at the moment would be to construct a complete new config tool that would create the jamfiles for me like I want them (preprocessor). However this is work I do not want to start, and I don't really believe that there is nothing out there that is able to do what seems to me like pretty common stuff. But probably I missed something completely...

Hope I explained it in an understandable way, thanks in advance!

Steve

Comment: It's probably best if you take this question up in the Boost Build list. As it requires some back and forth to answer and to better understand your use case.

Comment: Ok i'll give that a shot